# how to quickly dissolve sea shells?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Our condos are by the bay and seagulls are ubiquitous,so is their detritus. The shells they drop have been drawn by gravity and rain water to the down spouts and gutters of our buildings for 40 years and the drainage pipes underground are so backedup that the down spouts hadto be disconnected. Is there an economic way to dissolve the seashells quickly?

Comment: Not very quickly, not very economic, not very environment friendly.

Comment: And not likely to work without dissolving a metal drain.

Comment: I suspect the only real way is with mechanical means, beefier than the standard sewer cleanout snake, more like a root cutter. One might think the local plumbing companies would know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are high strength acid drain cleaners such as Rooto, which contain concentrated sulfuric acid, available at local hardware stores.  This would be for the underground pipes.  The downspouts and gutters can be manually cleaned.

Please be very careful with this approach, and first check the resistance of your underground pipes to acidic drain cleaners.

First cautious application of *dilute* acid is recommended, followed by a good water rinse.  If the pipes are good with this, keep at it until they flow well again. Be patient, and make sure you buy **acid** drain cleaner.  The basic ones, made with sodium hydroxide, will not work.

Comment: Sulfuric acid is not very good at the purpose in question.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I realize calcium sulfate has limited solubility, but it will break up calcium carbonate sea shells.  HCl may generate fumes.

Comment: My "not very good" was not a token of courtesy, but a realistic assessment of its capacity. It is not bad, no. Just not very good.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I welcome improvements or better ideas. [Here](https://www.goseeko.com/blog/what-is-gypsum) is evidence that sulfuric acid may be a better solvent than water.  HCl might be even better. Depends on the pipes.

Comment: Think I must apologize for looking somewhat judgemental. Chances are there is no ideal solution. H2SO4 is of course better than water, but, er, well, CaSO4. HCl (which would be my first choice) might be better still, but like you said, fumes. Also, both may damage pipes. Acetic acid is slow. So it goes.

Comment: @IvanNeretin no apology needed!  Calcium acetate has much higher solubility.  Appreciate the input. It is worth a try, perhaps on a small scale first.  3 acids in 3 different containers before adding to the pipes.  Work continues ...